# Can't use hyperref package with XeLaTeX

Tags: errors, xetex, hyperref, biber

I want to achieve a clickable URL in my bibliography using `\href`. I'm using custom document class for my course work and xelatex, biber to compile in Linux. The problem is that after adding a hyperref package it causes an error.

[Full LaTeX template repository.](https://github.com/LIKS/course_work_template_vu_mif_se)

Packages used:

```
\documentclass{VUMIFPSkursinis}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
```

If I try to add `\usepackage{hyperref}` I get this error:

```
[1] (./kursinis.toc
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \csname\endcsname 
l.5 ...tentsline {section}{Įvadas}{2}{section*.2}

?
```

Lines which causes the error:

```
\tableofcontents

\sectionnonum{Įvadas}
New paragraph here...
```

Software versions:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99992 (TeX Live 2015/Debian) (preloaded format=xelatex)
biber version: 2.4
```

Comment: It's impossible to help without a pointer to `VUMIFPSkursinis.cls`

Comment: Added link to the cls file.

Comment: ``! LaTeX Error: File `LTPlius.sty' not found``

Comment: I've added a link to the full template. It has all dependencies.

Comment: `! Package csquotes Error: Quote style not defined.` Moreover I see no `hyperref` loaded.

Comment: if you add hyperref the internal format of references changes so delete the .toc and .aux files then try again

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you, this worked for me. I've no idea how I missed this. I'm using `\url` in my custom bibliography. There's one small problem. My table of content, bibliography and source references has strange colours.

Comment: I've fixed it by using `\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you add hyperref the internal format of references changes so delete the .toc and .aux files then try again –